# Span of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v_1 = (1, 1, -1)$ and $v_2 = (-3, 2, -2)$. Which of the following vectors are in $\mathrm{span}\,\{v_1, v_2\}$?

(i) $(4, -1, 1)$

(ii) $(7, -3, 3)$

(iii) $(11, -4, 4)$

I tried to solve for the $c_1,c_2$ but I am really confused and only have 1 answer left, can someone please help???

Comment: You have three equations with two unknowns.  Do you see these equations?  If so, solve for the unknowns using two of the equations.  And then plug those values into the third equation.  If the answer is consistent, then the vector is in the span.  If it is not, then the vector is not in the span.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by equations. I created a matrix and tried to solve for c1 and c2

Comment: Perhaps, then, you’d care to show us exactly what you mean by “I tried to solve for the $c_1$, $c_2$...”

Comment: that's the thing, I checked other solutions and they had v3 but I don't

Answer (score 0):

Calculate $v_1-v_2$, $v_1-2c_2$ and $2v_1-3c_2$.

In case you've found that vector (i) and vector (ii) are in the span, save some work by observing that vector (iii) is the sum of both.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

We can somewhat 'simplify' the basis vectors by noting that the span of $v_1,v_2$ is also the span of $\dfrac{2v_1-v_2}5,\dfrac{3v_1+v_2}5\equiv(1,0,0),(0,1,-1)$. Now it's easy to see which vectors lie in the span.